# Spark streaming throws java.util.ConcurrentModificationException while adding JsonArray

Tags: java, arrays, exception, spark-streaming, concurrentmodification

I got an error during the following process. I'm aware that it seems like this error is thrown because it tried to read the whole records in the partition (rec) but trying to assign it to string (Str=jsonArray.toJSONString();) at the same time I'm using 5-sec batch interval in spark streaming configuration. Any suggestions for this code? Please kindly help. Thanks

The error is in this line :

```
 Str=jsonArray.toJSONString();
```

Below is my full function :

```
MapRowRDD.foreachRDD(rdd ->{
            rdd.foreachPartition(
                    rec-> {
                        while(rec.hasNext()) {
                            JSONObject record = rec.next();
                            i=i+1;
                          if(TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                                  .parse((String) record.get("DATE_TRANSACTION"))
                                  .getTime()-DateUtils.addMinutes(new Date(), -5)
                                  .getTime(),TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)>=0 || Integer.valueOf((String) record.get("EVENT_TYPE"))<0) {
                              jsonArray.add(record);
                            if(i % v_BATCH_WINDOW == 0)
                            {   
                                try {
                                    Str=jsonArray.toJSONString();
                                    HttpResponse<String> Response = ui.post(v_REST_API_ENDPOINT).body(Str).asString();
                                    out_JSON=Response.getBody();
                                    log.warn("Response : " + out_JSON.toString());
                                }
                                catch(UnirestConfigException e){
                                    System.out.println("UnirestConfigException occured "+ e.toString());
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                jsonArray.clear();
                                i=0;
                            }
                          }
                        publishToKafka(record.toString(), outputTopic, props);
                        }
                        Str=jsonArray.toJSONString();
                        if (!Str.equals("[]") && Str!=null && !Str.isEmpty()) {
                            HttpResponse<String> Response = ui.post(v_REST_API_ENDPOINT).body(Str).asString();
                        }
                        jsonArray.clear();
                        i=0;
                    }   
                    );
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

As you know this exception occurs when you modify and iterate the same collection at the same time via different threads. jsonArray is not thread-safe replace that with some thread-safe collections like Vector and see this works

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried to change JsonArray with StringBuilder. Afaik, string builder is not safe-thread, so I guess I can implement that thing inside my code